# Компонент js для отображения графиков

Tags: javascript, .net, диаграммы

Необходимо на сайте выводить график кусочно-линейной функции. Исходных данных (точек) около 50к. На текущий момент использую amchart, но он при таком количестве исходных данных вешает браузер. Рассматривал вариант собственной реализации в виде построенных изображений, т.е. на клиент тянется картинка с графиком, но такой подход медленно реагирует на действия пользователя по изменению масштаба и движению по графику влево-вправо.
В перспективе точек может быть еще больше, от 100к до 2м.

Смотрел в сторону CanvasJS. Проблема в том, что такой объем данных не выдержит ни один браузер, и если отдавать исходный набор данных в чистом виде. 
Подскажите пожалуйста компонент, который бы имел серверную реализацию (либо требования к ней, если не .net) подгрузки данных, чтобы полный набор данных оставался на сервере, а на клиент отдавался некий усредненный минимально необходимый набор для отрисовки графика, либо уже готовое изображение.

Интересует что-то похожее на графики zabbix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю подойдёт такой вариант:
https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading
Там есть и другие примеры с другими типами графиков. К сожалению это не бесплатно, но у них есть программы для стартапов.

Если писать своё, то можно посмотреть d3.js + сделать динамическую загрузку данных.

Рисовать картинку на сервере я бы не стал, под нагрузкой ляжет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Хайчарты смотрел, но, к сожалению не нашел у них как двигать влево-вправо зазумленный график.
А вот d3 уже более интересный вариант, примеров много, пока близкого к моему не нашел, но буду разбираться

Comment: @AlexanderFresh про [двигать зумленное с шифтом](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/pankey/), про [500к точек](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-boost/dark-unica), это про чарт, а не сток